# Automatic inclusion of runtime library/framework into the installation package VS2008

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, deployment, microsoft-runtime-library

- Project1: A C++ EXE project with code
  generation option "runtime library" set to
  "Multithreaded Debug Dll".
- Project2: A C# EXE project developed
  with .Net Version, say, 3.5

Suppose I want to write an installer project for these projects. I naturally include their primary outputs (the exe's) in the installation package. But the exe's are not sufficient to ensure that they will be runnable on the target machine. In case of project1 we will need msvcrt.dll and possibly others(not sure), and, in case of project2 we will need the .NET framework of the corresponding version. The question is, is it possible to make the installation package *automatically* include those? If it is *not*, how is it best done manually? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already automatic afaik.  Every time I tinkered with a Setup project, it already figured out the prerequisites from the projects I added.  From your Setup project, use Project + Properties and click Prerequisites.  Verify that the right Visual C++ Runtime Libraries and .NET Framework are ticked.

Comment: Thanks. I never saw that "Prerequisites" button.